# What is the relationship between Java Library and Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I wanted to learn Kotlin but after reading online most experts seem to agree that learning Java first would be a first step in the roadmap of learning Kotlin. Their argument based on the fact that Kotlin developers may use Java Library. However, I don't understand what is the point of learning Java if I'm at the end only going to use Java Library. Even Fundamentals courses in Java don't mention the Java Library!

Comment: While your "Fundamentals" course may not have mentioned it by name, you were certainly using the [Java Class Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library).

Answer (score 2):

Basically kotlin can be thought of mostly Java with much much better syntax and a handful of very useful libraries. But any real world kotlin project is going to be using lots of base java libraries.

Kotlin is meant to be interchangeable with Java to such a degree that a single project can have both kotlin and Java files in it, so you need to know both and you need to know the quirks of Java as many of it's quirks are in kotlin as well.

Comment: You probably only really need three things from Java: Being able to read method signatures, understanding of Generics and Type erasure - that will let you get to grips with most Java libraries that you would typically use in Kotlin (JVM)